# user data as variable in shiny

Tags: r, session, shiny, observers, openair

I am building an app to analyze wind data using the packages “shiny” and “openair”.

I am trying to read the input data given by the user and use it as variables, but I keep getting:

```r
Error in updateSelectInput(session, "pollutant", choices = names(df)) : 
  object 'session' not found
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

In the ui.r I have:

```r
selectInput("pollutant", "Please choose pollutant", names(userdata))
```

and in the server.r:

```r
observe({
    df <- userdata()
    str(names(df))
    if (!is.null(df)) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "pollutant", choices = names(df))   
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're not including the `session` variable in the server definition? i.e. use `(input, output, session)` rather than just `(input, output)`.